# View caching for Headers and footers in a list view

Tags: java, android

It is possible to add header and footer views to a list views.Are these views cached?
Like the get view mechanism ensures recycling view resources for the list and prevents excess memory consumption.Is a header/footer view also taken care similarly?

**EDIT**

Consider a layout(which is essentially a ) with such contents:

- About 40 different fields divided into 5 viewgroups
- a comments type layout which can have an arbit number of comments which need to expanded at will.

Ideally a scroll view would be a suitable candidate for this.
But this makes the choreographer complain about skipping a 1000 odd frames.

Another possible solution could be a a list view with headers and footers.
A list view somehow consumes lower memory wrt the aforementioned scroll view.

The caching and parcelling questions was me trying to understand if there can be a mechanism for view storing/retrieving which would make inflation and relocing of listeners an easier task instead of a *one-for-all-purpose* method like `getView()`

**EDIT2**
I do not want to use a scroll view since it would inflate all the views in the start.Making the activity/fragment consume a lot of memory

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I don't understand the part about caching. The header and footer views aren't recycled since they aren't reused and exist only once.

Comment: @MithunR. If it is,please add an answer.I'd really like to know

Answer (score 3):

> It is possible to add header and footer views to a list views

yes ListView has the [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)) and [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View))

> Like the get view mechanism ensures recycling view reosurces for the
>   list and prevents excess memory consumption. Is a header/footer view
>   also taken care similarly?

No they are not.

In particular you can call both methods more than once. In this case you will have more footer/header views, and they will appear in the order of the insertion

Comment: But i presume the view object would be parcelled or bundled somehow?Or does view caching nto come into factor here?

Comment: View caching? Parcelled? Why?

Comment: Imagine a list view with header and footer and only 1 layout in between.This is essentially a scrollview with 3 children.But the memory consumption of the scrollview is more than that of the listview.Why?

Comment: no it is not. In this case ListView will require more memory, because internally it allocates an array of views equal to the number of views needed to fill up completely your screen.

Comment: In the case of just a header footer and single list item, Listview would be more memory intensive. It would become more performant than the scrollview depending on how many items there are in the list. If you want to have the header and footer views recycled as well, you could consider inflating them as actual views in the list view by getting the position in the adapter (inflate header at position 0, inflate footer at position adapter.getCount() - 1). This would ensure they are recycled

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. It may be useful for you.

- Initially Header and footer layout is created as far the requirement.
- Inflate these views and add it to the list view.

Ref: https://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/

Comment: This just shows how to add header and footer to a listview.My question is whether it is possible to cache or recycler these specifically.I am looking towards an answer which shows lesser memory consumption and the least number of inflated views.This header/footer would always be inflated.